# Can Any one knows how to post image array to server in android?

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm entangled in a query in which I need to send an image array to server.

I googled it but I couldn't find any relevant data, so can any one tell me how can I achieve it?

Early reply is appreciable .

My code is

```
private void imageUpload(final ArrayList imagePath) {

   SimpleMultiPartRequest smr = new SimpleMultiPartRequest( 
            Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(String response) {
                   Log.d( "Response", response );
                   try {
                       JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject( response );
                       String message = jObj.getString( "message" );
                       System.out.println( "Done" );

                       Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       // JSON error
                       e.printStackTrace();
                       Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                   }
               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

       }
   });

    for (int i = 0; i<imagePath.size();i++){
        String ab = imagePath.get( i ).toString();
        System.out.println("Images is find path "+ab);
        smr.addFile(""+i,imagePath.get(i).toString());
    }

    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(smr);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: see [Posting a multipart request](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-multipart-request)

Comment: @pskink i asking how to send array as a parameter . Please suggest only on that

Comment: @pskink dear i simply want to send a array of image to server , as well in  above code also i pass array as a parameter in the method and try to post that array but still i am not find any solution to achieve it , If you have any logic than please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

I am using https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker this library to get images list

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.upload_btn:
            openImagesList();
            break;
    }
}

public void openImagesList() {
    ImagePicker.create(this) // Activity or Fragment
            .start();

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, final int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (ImagePicker.shouldHandle(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // Get a list of picked images
        List<Image> images = ImagePicker.getImages(data);
        List<File> imgFile = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Image imge : images) {
            imgFile.add(new File(imge.getPath()));
        }

        for (File f : imgFile) {
            if (f.exists()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "exist");
            }
        }

        uploadToSever(imgFile);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Use https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking to POST request

```
   public void uploadToSever(List<File> imgList) {
    AndroidNetworking.upload("your sever url")
            .addMultipartFileList("image[]", imgList)
            .addMultipartParameter("key", "value")
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .setUploadProgressListener(new UploadProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(long bytesUploaded, long totalBytes) {
                    // do anything with progress
                }
            })
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // do anything with response
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                    // handle error
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Madu_dev for your quick response . I applied your logic but it throw com.androidnetworking.error.ANError .

Comment: did you remove this .addMultipartParameter("key", "value") part if you have values only you can pass within here .if not just remove this line

Comment: yes I removed it , I only pass Image and it throw -> com.androidnetworking.error.ANError

Comment: .addMultipartFileList("image[]", imgList) do you have idea about `image[]` this parameter ? you need give you url query parameter for this.

Comment: yeah i know that , I pass the same parameter define on server

Comment: do you have github ?

Comment: do you have repository for this project ?

Comment: no i dont have repository for this project you can upload your source and add me to that repository.

Comment: Send your email I will mail you

Comment: findos1995@gmail.com its my gmail account , please connect over there